# Error: Selected location data is not supported | AWS quicksite | geospatialMaps | Longitude and Latitude

Tags: amazon-web-services, geospatial, amazon-quicksight

Hi I am attaching  the Image , even though I have co-ordinates data I am not able to visualize geospatial maps can anybody suggest what are the possible problems/solutions for this  [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCdPL.png)